# Aggregating using Spring mongo group after a project is not finding the correct field

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have a collection with a dataset that looks like:

```
{
    "resource" : "10.10.10.10",
    "statistics" : {
        "connections" : 17
    }
}
{
    "resource" : "10.10.10.10",
    "statistics" : {
        "connections" : 24
    }
}
```

I want to use Mongo's $group/$push mechanism to return a dataset that looks like:

```
{ "_id" : "10.10.10.10", "statTotals" : [ 17, 24 ] }
```

In Mongo shell, I can that by doing:

```
db.testcol.aggregate([ { "$project" : { "resource" : 1 , "total" : "$statistics.connections"}} , { "$group" : { "_id" : "$resource" , "statTotals" : { "$push" : "$total"}}} ])
```

Now I want to do this using Spring's Mongo data solution in Java. The operations I'm currently trying to use are:

```
ProjectionOperation projOper = Aggregation.project("resource").and("statistics.connections").as("total");
GroupOperation groupOper = Aggregation.group("resource").push("total").as("statTotals");
```

Unfortunately, this is generating a pipeline which looks like:

```
{ "aggregate" : "event" , "pipeline" : [ { "$project" : { "resource" : 1 , "total" : "$statistics.connections"}} , { "$group" : { "_id" : "$resource" , "statTotals" : { "$push" : "$statistics.connections"}}}]}
```

In the $group, the $push is being done against $statistics.connections instead of $total so the results come back blank.

Any help would be greatly appreciated on this. At first I thought this might be https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1254 but I've tried using both 1.7.2 as well as 1.8.1 and get the same results.

Comment: What is unfortunate about this? It's doing the right thing that you should be doing yourself anyway. The `$project` would add an in-efficiency in the pipeline that is seemingly being correctly removed as an optimization. Your code should be doing this anyway.

Comment: What's unfortunate about it is it generates a broken pipeline. Yes, I agree that the initial project is in-efficient and could be removed but I would still expect it to not create a broken pipeline if we choose to add a project there.

Comment: MongoDb Aggregation pipeline operations have an [optimization phase](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/). So I think MongodB reshapes the aggregation pipeline for improve performance.

Comment: This seems to be happening in Spring before it even gets to Mongo. The group is supposed to be pushing $total since that's what was projected in the first part of the pipeline. Instead though it's replaced it with $statistics.connections again which doesn't exist because of the project in the first part of the pipeline. This causes no data to be returned in the statTotals response.

Comment: @hecnabae Whilst it is true that MongoDB would optimize internally after sent to the server, this is actually also being done by spring mongo before sending the request to the server. But the assertion that this is "broken" is incorrect. It is actually what should "optimally" be done. Which is the lesson to learn here.

Comment: I guess I just have to move on. I don't understand how this is not broken. If it also optimized out the project as well then it would make sense to me. Maybe this is my mistake for not showing what the results are with this? The results I get back are wrong and have statTotals: [] instead of statTotals: [17, 24] which is what I get if I manually run the aggregate query through the shell and use total instead of statistics.connections liked I passed to the push arg. So when I say broken, I mean its "optimizations" are causing the wrong data to be returned.